# Combine text elements in a data frame and remove rows the text came from

Tags: r, copy-paste

This toy data frame represents time entries by Persons.  The format available to me has multiple Text entries for the same person and day in a totally random pattern.  There can be as many as 15 Text entries for the same person and day.  No Person entry is in the row for a multiple-text entry.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1514764800, 1514764800, NA, 
1517443200, 1519862400, NA, NA, NA, 1519862400, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Person = c("FMC", "ABC", NA, "FMC", 
"ABC", NA, NA, NA, "RWM", NA, NA), Text = c("work on request", 
"More text", "third line", "email to re: summary", "work on loan documents", 
"sixth line of text", "text seven", "eighth in a series", "conferences with working group", 
"line ten", "review and provide comments")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I combine the text elements so that there is only one line for each person's entry **for each day**, drop the unneeded rows (once the text is pasted together) and arrive at the following object?

[image]

EDITED QUESTION omits the `for` loop I tried unsuccessfully.

There must be a way to combine all the text into one row for a given person for a given day (for example, ABC has two entries on 1/1/2018) and delete the row(s) from which the combined text came.

Comment: I improved the data frame to include dates and clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get complicated, just use `tidyverse`.

**Adjusted per changes to question:**

```
library(tidyverse)

> df%>%
   fill(Date:Person, Date:Person) %>% # Fills missing values in using the previous entry.
   group_by(Date, Person) %>%
   summarise(Text = paste(Text, collapse = ' '))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Date                Person Text                                                                   
  <dttm>              <chr>  <chr>                                                                  
1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ABC    More text third line                                                   
2 2018-01-01 00:00:00 FMC    work on request                                                        
3 2018-02-01 00:00:00 FMC    email to re: summary                                                   
4 2018-03-01 00:00:00 ABC    work on loan documents sixth line of text text seven eighth in a series
5 2018-03-01 00:00:00 RWM    conferences with working group line ten review and provide comments
```

**Data:**

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   Date                Person Text                          
   <dttm>              <chr>  <chr>                         
 1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 FMC    work on request               
 2 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ABC    More text                     
 3 NA                  NA     third line                    
 4 2018-02-01 00:00:00 FMC    email to re: summary          
 5 2018-03-01 00:00:00 ABC    work on loan documents        
 6 NA                  NA     sixth line of text            
 7 NA                  NA     text seven                    
 8 NA                  NA     eighth in a series            
 9 2018-03-01 00:00:00 RWM    conferences with working group
10 NA                  NA     line ten                      
11 NA                  NA     review and provide comments
```

Comment: Please check OP's expected output and discussion in comments on @prossitos 's answer.

Comment: @RonakShah OPs expected output and  discussion in comments differ. I changed the answer to match expected output.

Comment: @avenger012: I clarified the question and data frame to keep dates separate.  Are you able to modify you answer to deal with the changed question?

Comment: @lawyeR I adjusted my answer per your new question.

Comment: Both answers work (1st and 3rd) but I checked the dplyr one because it doesn't introduce more packages.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `na.locf` to fill the missing values (`NA`) with last non-missing value, then `group_by` consecutive occurrence of `Person` and `summarise` `Text` by `paste`ing it together.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  na.locf(.) %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(Person)) %>%
  summarise(Text = paste0(Text, collapse = " "))


#  group Text                                                                   
#  <int> <chr>                                                                  
#1     1 work on request                                                        
#2     2 More text third line                                                   
#3     3 email to re: summary                                                   
#4     4 work on loan documents sixth line of text text seven eighth in a series
#5     5 conferences with working group line ten review and provide comments
```

---

For the updated question, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>%
  na.locf(.) %>%
  group_by(Date, Person) %>%
  summarise(Text = paste0(Text, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: very close, but I have clarified the question to keep dates separate.  Are you able to modify you answer to deal with the changed question?

Comment: @lawyeR if you include `Date` column here then it makes it much simpler. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

merge_lines <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' ')

df %>% 
  zoo::na.locf(.) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Text), (funs(merge_lines)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Person Text                                                                   
  <chr>  <chr>                                                                  
1 ABC    More text third line                                                   
2 FMC    work on request email to re: summary                                   
3 HIL    work on loan documents sixth line of text text seven eighth in a series
4 RWM    conferences with working group line ten review and provide comments
```

Comment: your output for `FMC` gets merged into one. OP wants to keep it separate.

Comment: lol. I was looking at your answer and I thought you were the one who made a mistake. I don't understand why both `FMC` should be kept separate. What am I missing? Could it be a typo from the OP??

Comment: Oh, got it. It's because they must be on different days

Comment: It would have been a lot simpler not to remove the day variable. Then you can `group_by(Day, User)`

Comment: I am assuming OP wants to group consecutive missing and non-missing value in one group. So Row 1 is group 1, row 2, 3 is group 2, row 4 is group 3 and so on. Looking at OP's expected output gives that impression. We can wait for OP to clarify though.

Comment: Yes, but OP also says: "How can I combine the text elements so that there is only one line for each person's entry for a day""

Comment: So it is unclear... If both `FMC` are for different days, then your answer is correct. But if they are on the same day, they should be combined. Without the `day` variable, we can't know

Comment: I guess your interpretation must be correct since the OP's expected output matches your answer. I was confused by the above statement, but I guess it only meant: "How can I combine the text elements so that there is only one line for each person's entry" and I took it as wanting to combine all entries "for a day". So, I'll +1 your answer :)

Comment: But if there is only one entry per person per day, then `df %>% zoo::na.locf(.) %>% group_by(Day, Person) %>% summarise(Text = paste(Text, collapse = " "))` should do it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I thought I was creating the most minimal example by omitting the day variable.  The first person was correct that FMC, for example, has entries on different days.  I do not want to combine them all.  Thanks to all.

Comment: No worries. If this is the case and if you only have one entry per person per day, and if you don't want to use an extra package, the code I posted just above should also work

Comment: No real point for me editing my answer with your adjusted question I guess since all 3 answers are now pretty much the same. And my edited answer is what I already posted in a comment just above (replace `Day` with `Date`). And as @RonakShah said, with the date, it makes the solution a lot simpler